# Automate Boring Stuff with Python, Chapter 6 Practice Project

Tags: python, for-loop, newline

I have a short questions regarding the solution of Chapter 6 Practice Project in "Automate Boring Stuff with Python" book. I should write a function that take data in teh form of list of lists:

```
tableData = [['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
             ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
             ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]
```

and prints the following table with each column right-justified:

```
  apples Alice  dogs
 oranges   Bob  cats
cherries Carol moose
  banana David goose
```

The problem is, that my code:

```
def printTable(table):
    colsWidths = [0]*len(table) #this variable will be used to store width of each column
    # I am using max function with key=len on each list in the table to find the longest string --> it's length be the length of the colum
    for i in range(len(table)):
        colsWidths[i] = len(max(table[i], key = len)) # colsWidths = [8,5,5]
    # Looping through the table to print columns
    for i in range(len(table[0])):
        for j in range(len(table)):
            print(table[j][i].rjust(colsWidths[j], " "), end = " ")
        print("\n")
```

prints the table with excessive empty lines between each row:

```
printTable(tableData)

  apples Alice  dogs

 oranges   Bob  cats

cherries Carol moose

  banana David goose
```

I understand that it has something to do with the print statement that is written at  the end of the program, but without it everything is printed. So my question is, is there a way to remove those empty rows from the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `print("\n")` with `print()`

`print` by default prints a newline character, that's what the default value of `end` parameter is.

When you do `print("\n")` you are actually printing two new lines.